# building hostpython3 for armeabi-v7a -- RuntimeError: release unlocked lock

Tags: android, python, kivy

I am attempting to make some progress on my other issue here --> [Kivy Launcher - AttributeError: ‘MyInputs’ object has no attribute ‘get_focus_next’](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54831979/kivy-launcher-attributeerror-myinputs-object-has-no-attribute-get-focus-ne)

My intent now is to build Kivy Launcher (alternate suggestions on ways to prototype android python apps are welcome, but regardless I still would like to complete this).  However, I've hit a new roadblock.  Python-for-android is failing a long ways through the build, specifically it is failing as shown below.

The build command:

```
p4a apk --requirements=python2,kivy --permission WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE --name="R Kivy Launcher" --package=com.kivy.rkivylauncher --version=0.0.1 --android_api 28 --bootstrap=pygame --launcher --minsdk 13
```

The error stuff (below that, is the system and configuration stuff I think might be important):

```
    [INFO]:    Building hostpython3 for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    -> directory context /home/Me/.local/share/python-for-android/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3
[INFO]:    -> directory context /home/Me/.local/share/python-for-android/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/native-build
[INFO]:    -> running configure
           working: checking for dup3... yes                                                                                                                                                                             raceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/queue.py", line 179, in get
    self.not_empty.wait(remaining)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 288, in wait
    raise RuntimeError("cannot wait on un-acquired lock")
RuntimeError: cannot wait on un-acquired lock

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/p4a", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 1075, in main
    ToolchainCL()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 577, in __init__
    getattr(self, args.subparser_name.replace('-', '_'))(args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 151, in wrapper_func
    build_dist_from_args(ctx, dist, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 200, in build_dist_from_args
    build_recipes(build_order, python_modules, ctx)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pythonforandroid/build.py", line 562, in build_recipes
    recipe.build_arch(arch)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pythonforandroid/python.py", line 417, in build_arch
    sh.Command(join(recipe_build_dir, 'configure')))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pythonforandroid/logger.py", line 178, in shprint
    for line in output:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sh.py", line 857, in next
    chunk = self.process._pipe_queue.get(True, 0.001)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/queue.py", line 182, in get
    return item
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 244, in __exit__
    return self._lock.__exit__(*args)
RuntimeError: release unlocked lock
```

System: 
  Cygwin 3.0.3

Configuration:
 - Python 3.7
 - python-for-android 0.7.1
 - buildozer 0.39
 - sdk-tools-linux-4333796.zip
 - android-ndk-r19b-linux-x86_64.zip (is
   there an AMD specific variant?  So far, Google says no...)

Happy to share more, just not really sure what else is important / potentially related.  I have some totally wild suspicions (Cygwin and threading / lock incompatibilities?), but that's all I got.

Help?

Comment: Answering my own question (sort of) above: While I now understand there are a lot of set up requirements that are possible to allow direct use of p4a, in the end I figured out the following in general:

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question (sort of) above: While I now understand there are a lot of set up requirements that are possible to allow direct use of p4a, in the end I realized the following in general:

1. My dedicated Linux box with 'Buildozer Android' turned out to be (eventually) the fastest / easiest to manage option for me.  It just handles all the proper downloading and aligning of the components needed to make the build happen right.  The new python3 version of Kivy Launcher installs, and starts with a list of apps available just like the one in the App Store, but alas it still crashes (and I'm still trying to figure out why, but I'm closer...)

On the path to this realization, I found:

1. Cygwin has some deep seated issues creating apk's - I'm still not certain whether the issues I experienced were directly due to the Cygwin environment, my Cygwin setup, my test App and the depreciated ListView stuff I had in it, my Computer Virus protection or a strong and unmanageable combination of the above.
2. I also struggled for a while trying to get MSYS2 and Mingw-w64 64 bit to build kivy stuff natively and for Android, but the whole Windows vs Unix pathname mixing, environment setup and a hundred other things proved too much of a distraction from my real goal : building an App to run natively on many platforms --> Mingw may still end up playing a role in the future but it's on the bookshelf for now.
3. I also tried Termux.  And Eclipse.  And looked into ways to make the new Android Studio work with Python.  All might be possible (or none), and I really see the value in the idea of Eclipse and Android Studio for creating visual app front ends, so again those may find a future use as this project matures.

All in all, I want to thank many hundreds of people all over the internet - I had almost 80 tabs open at one time (plus multi-tab bookmarks saved!) to get to this point : With all the info available on Buildozer and why it works so well on a Linux machine, I ended where I probably should have started.  My prototype kivy app runs on an Android phone, and (I hope soon) the Kivy Launcher will also.  It seems the new relaunched Kivy Launcher fails in a way that makes me believe the 'ListView" depreciation is the reason it's crashing (it builds, starts to load the sample apps included, but then crashes and the logs are not so helpful as I'd hoped).  If I can confirm and refactor it to fix this, I'll have something real to contribute back myself.

Stay tuned to the first link in my original post above if you care more about a new Kivy Launcher than you care about tools to build apk's - I'm hoping to add one more entry if I do indeed get Kivy Launcher working again with all the new kivy and python3 functionality I need.  Now I just have to figure out RecycleView...